# Is it ever ok to use public fields in Java?

Tags: java, public

The question in the title is a little generic and many other similar questions have already been answered so I understand the general picture. Mainly, the use of a public field in a Java class creates dependance to the implementation details of the class, which leads to less mantainable software.

With that in mind, I still got the feeling that I can use them somehow. To explain this, I will use an example: with the upcoming of Java 8's functional interfaces I finally can use a event model that I like, which is similar to how events are dealt with in C#.

The event model is implemented in a package which is intended to be used as a third party API in all my projects.
Those are the main classes:

EventArgs.java

```
public class EventArgs implements Serializable {
}
```

EventHandler.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EventHandler<T extends EventArgs> {
    void fire(Object sender, T args);
}
```

Event.java

```
public class Event<T extends EventArgs> {

    private final Set<EventHandler<T>> handlers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void addEventHandler(EventHandler<T> handler) {
        handlers.add(handler);
    }

    public void removeEventHandler(EventHandler<T> handler) {
        handlers.remove(handler);
    }

    public void fire(Object sender, T args) {
        for (EventHandler<T> e : handlers) {
            e.fire(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

What I usually like to do in my classes that want to fire events is something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public final Event<SomeEventArgs> someEvent = new Event<>();

    public void someMethod() {
         // ...
         someEvent.fire();
    }
}
```

and in the classes that want to subscribe the event:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {
    private SomeClass someInstance;

    public SomeOtherClass() {
        someInstance = new SomeClass();
        someInstance.someEvent.addEventHandler(this::someEventHandler);
    }

    private void someEventHandler(Object sender, SomeEventArgs args) {
         // do some stuff ...
    }
}
```

To me this seems fine because I am not exposing any implementation details, actually the event is part of the interface of the class.
Am I completely wrong on this? Shoud I still use a getter to interact with the event?

Another example that I can think of is a logger that is used in the class but can be set from the outside to get a certain level of detail.

So, to extend the question, is it ok to use a public modifier if the field is a third party component that can be accessed to achieve a specific behaviour?

Comment: I'm not active on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) but this might have been a better fit there.

Comment: Having an `Event` hold the event handlers is a little odd, and that's why you have ended up with `public` variables seeming like a good idea. Re-read [The Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I think that's the whole point with functional interfaces. I think it's not like the `Event` holds the handler itself, it's more like the `Event` holds an anonymous delegate object that implements the functional interface, I don't see anything wrong with that. Actually it seems to me it is very similar to the observer patter itself.

Comment: If you look at libraries that handle this situation routinely, Swing, GWT etc... Then you'll find that `SomeClass` has the `addXXXHandler` methods directly - it implements some `HasXXXHandler` interface (see [`BeanContextChild`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/beancontext/BeanContextChild.html)). It would then delegate to some sort of handler support which maintains the `event -> handler` mapping (for example [`PropertyChangeSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html)). I think your code violates encapsulation.

Comment: My `Event` class is somehow similar to `PropertyChangeSupport`, the only difference is the functional interface used. If I got it right I shoud declare my event private and implement `addEventHandler` and `removeEventHandler` inside `SomeClass`? This way if I have five events I need ten among adder and remover.

Comment: I'm not a massive fan of having the `Event` also being `PropertyChangeSupport` as it ties these two together - if you were to have many different event classes (`DeleteEvent`, `CreateEvent`, etc.) then I'm not sure your code works so well. But yes, your `SomeClass` should have the `addXXX` and `removeXXX` methods, and encapsulate that behaviour in `SomeClass`. That's my opinion though. I am generally of the opinion that there's a better option than a `public` field except in rare cases (`public static final`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason you can declare fields public, but besides simple transport-objects like maybe a two-dimensional point, ... declaring a field public may lead to unexpected results.

Lets look at `SomeClass` and extends it into `SomeChildClass` and `SomeGrandChildClass` like this:

```
public class SomeChildClass extends SomeClass {

    public SomeChildClass() {
         super();
         someEvent.addEventHandler(...);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeGrandChildClass extends SomeChildClass  {

    public SomeGrandChildClass() {
         super();
         // Lets say FilteredEvent will ensure a Event will only be fired if a condition holds
         someEvent = new FilteredEvent();
    }
}
```

So what happened? We just lost an `EventHandler` because of the sequence of calls between super-constructors and constructor. I can think of different situations where it seems a good idea to replace a certain `Event` by a specific implementation from the outside (as the field is public). You could of course use `public final` to prevent reassignment, but then again you loose the opportunity to override behavior in sub-classes as well.

So `Event`-class is cool with me, but implementing `addSomeHandler`- and `removeSomeHandler`-methods ensures that sub-classes can use a different event-management and include parent-listeners, if they also use the override-able functions.

Other example can be a change of the `Event`-handling mechanism. If you implement this short methods you can instantly wrap the old-style handlers, assign them to additional `Event`s, ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle there is nothing wrong with having public, or more generally non-private, fields in Java. It's supported by the Java language and there certainly are use cases for them. Having said that, personally I tend to only use them in non-public, often nested auxiliary classes. In classes which are going to be used outside of their packages I want to validate the values of the properties or forbid the user to modify instances of the class, I want to wrap collections in unmodifiable views, substitute default values for null values, etc. And when I don't want that now, I usually want to be able to add them later without breaking to much code. So I would say: no, non-private fields have no place in classes which belong to the public interface of a package.

In your specific case, for me an event is an object that encapsulates the information of one specific event, for example a single key press or a single mouse click, etc. So I find it odd to store the event listeners in the event object itself, because this would mean that the event listeners have to be added each time an event occurs. For me an event is a key example of a class which should probably be unmodifiable. Having public fields immediately makes an instance of the class modifiable, so in event object I would especially advice against public fields.